# How to create the following page with beamer?

Tags: beamer

I want to create a page like the following (as perfect as possible). The texts are horizontally centered.

[image]

My attempt produces the following. I don't know the font, the background pattern, etc. However, background pattern is not so important so solid color is just fine.

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{beamer}
\usetheme{rochester}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{}
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.33\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=2]{croppingwithnavigation}
    \end{center}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.33\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=3]{croppingwithnavigation}
    \end{center}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.33\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=4]{croppingwithnavigation}
    \end{center}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
Media Marketing\\
Contract package
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Question

How to achieve the desired result?

The important parts are prioritized as the following order.

- layout and dimension (size)
- font
- background pattern, etc

Comment: Are you asking to produce the background patterns or does your question only concern the layout? And do you want someone to find the fonts or are you fine with the beamer fonts?

Comment: @marmot: See my update question.

Comment: Sorry if I am asking so critically. Why beamer? If you want to use this slide, why can't you just include it as graphics? Why do you include `croppingwithnavigation` images which AFAIK are not part of the TeX distributions and are just some black rectangles instead of drawing them? And if you want the lowest text centered, why not using `overlayarea` and `\centering`? And finally, who else will benefit from an answer? (Please do not get me wrong, I don't want to criticize you, but I am just wondering...)

Comment: The images are intentionally kept confidential. Showing them here will cause problems to me. Beamer is needed because I love it. Shortly speaking, I want to learn how to get the layout done with beamer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of your question is opinion specific. so i limited myself to layout, colors, patterns i left to you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{beamer}
\usetheme{rochester}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
%\usepackage{graphicx} it is loaded by bemaer
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\setbeamercolor{father}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{mother}{bg=green}
\setbeamercolor{child}{parent={father,mother}}
\begin{beamercolorbox}{child}
Terrible red on green text.
\end{beamercolorbox}
\setbeamercolor{father}{fg=blue}
\begin{beamercolorbox}{child}
Now terrible blue on green text, since parent was changed.
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamercolor{slidebackground}{bg=blue!30}
\setbeamercolor{titlebackground}{bg=gray!30!yellow!20, fg=gray}

    \begin{beamercolorbox}{slidebackground}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2ex\relax}{XXX}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=2]{croppingwithnavigation}
&       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=3]{croppingwithnavigation}
&       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=4]{croppingwithnavigation}
\end{tabularx}\\[1em]

\mbox{}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\dimexpr\linewidth-2ex-6pt\relax,center]{titlebackground}

        \medskip\Large\bfseries
Media Marketing\\[1ex]
    \normalsize\normalfont
\emph{Contract package}\\[1em]
        \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{center}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**
in case that whole frame is colored, you should redefine `background canas` for this frame:

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{beamer}
\usetheme{rochester}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!30}
\begin{frame}
\setbeamercolor{titlebackground}{bg=gray!30!yellow!20, fg=gray}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2ex\relax}{XXX}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=2]{croppingwithnavigation}
&       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=3]{croppingwithnavigation}
&       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=4]{croppingwithnavigation}
\end{tabularx}\\[1em]

\mbox{}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\dimexpr\linewidth-2ex-6pt\relax,center]{titlebackground}

        \medskip\Large\bfseries
Media Marketing\\[1ex]
    \normalsize\normalfont
\emph{Contract package}\\[1em]
        \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: which white borders? that blue box start and end at frame border? or that all frame is in the blue?